# TypeScript + React: How do I type a component that passes props to an html `img` element?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have a simple component `Bar` that passes props to a `<img />`

```js
function Bar(props: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>) {
  return <img {...props} />;
}
```

Ideally when I use `<Bar />` it should asks me to pass `src` and `alt` for the underlying `img` tag but it is not working that way. Also the autocomplete seems not working.

Live demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/type-images-66y2s?file=/src/App.tsx

Any ideas?

[image]

Comment: Check this https://codesandbox.io/s/type-images-forked-l7v9i . You are giving `props: React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>` but whereas the props value will be an object like `{alt: string, src: string}` ..

Answer (score 3):

Try the below code to define props for your Bar component

```
function Bar(
props: React.DetailedHTMLProps<
    React.ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>,
    HTMLImageElement
>,) {
return <img {...props} />;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just press `cmd` on Mac or `ctrl` on Windows focusing on the `img` tag and then click the mouse, you will see `IntrinsicElements` set.

```js
function Bar(props: React.DetailedHTMLProps<React.ImgHTMLAttributes<HTMLImageElement>, HTMLImageElement>) {
  return <img {...props} />
}
```